# Shape Detection Using Hough Transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hough-transform, shape-recognition

I'm using a Properly working Matlab code (The original code is from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9275-simple-shape-detection-using-hough-transform)) that uses Hough trnsform to detect basic shapes like round, square and triangle.Here below is the important code segment.

```
[H, theta,rho]=hough(S);
```

Above H is the Hough transform matrix and S is the Black and White image of the shape.

```
for cnt = 1:max(max(H))
    data(cnt) = sum(sum(H == cnt));
end
```

Here is the shape detection part.

```
[maxval,maxind] = max(data);
medval = median(data);

[p]=polyfit(1:maxind-5,data(1:maxind-5),2);

if maxval<3*medval
    set(handles.txtResult,'string','Triangle');
elseif  p(3)>100
    set(handles.txtResult,'string','Square');
else
    set(handles.txtResult,'string','Round'); 
end
```

I can understand the "data"(which stores Hough Matrix intensity frequencies).  I just can't understand the logic it uses to detect the shape. `maxval<3*medval` and `p(3)>100`

Comment: This has to do with the model used to construct `H`. Can you post the code for computing `H` as well?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. I edited the question. Now I think there is no more confusion on `H`. It's the typical hough transform matrix.

Comment: You can find some more information in the code author's related [blog post](http://basic-eng.blogspot.com/2005/12/object-detection-using-hough-transform_06.html?m=1). It seems this method is rather heuristic and not guaranteed to work. I think there are some assumptions here on the size of the shape and of the image which are not mentioned in the function description

Comment: Yes I tried to find about it on the blog. He hasn't described it well. Thanks for the advice. It seems you are correct. I also feel that it is not the best method.

Comment: I think it's meant more as an illustrative, simple example. You can try running some shapes and plotting their Hough matrix and frequencies, and maybe these criteria will make more sense. I wouldn't count on it working on more general input, though.

Comment: I saw most of the people referring this Matlab program in most answers on Hough. That's why I tried to understand it. Ok I'll try to make more sense on it by giving different image files externally or I have to go for a another code. If you think this question and comments will help to others, feel free to vote up. Ok Thanks for the help.